# параметрический конструктор

Tags: c++

помогите пожалуйста понять что здесь написано:

```
MyStruct(MyStruct  *p)  :  _p(p)  {}
```

Т.е. я не понял что такое написано после двоеточия, что это означает ?
Почему в классе MyStructPtr  функция MyStruct названа конструктором ?

Встретил в книге пример:

```
//  Same  structure  as  before
class  MyStruct  {
MyStruct()  {}  //  constructor
~MyStruct()  {}  //  destructor
myFunction()  {}  //  member  function
};
//  Declare  a  smart  pointer  for  MyStruct
class  MyStructPtr  {
public:
//  Constructor:  simply  save  the  pointer
MyStruct(MyStruct  *p)  :  _p(p)  {
}
//  Destructor:  call  the  delete  operator
~MyStruct()  {
delete  _p;
}
//  replace  operator  ->  to  return  the  actual  pointer
MyStruct*  operator->()  {
return  _p;
}
private:
//  a  pointer  to  the  MyStruct  instance
MyStruct  *_p;
};
//  create  the  instance  of  MyStruct,
//  capture  the  pointer  in  a  smart  pointer
MyStructPtr  p(new  MyStruct());
//  call  the  member  function  as  if  we  were  using  a  raw  pointer
p->myFunction();
//  the  destructor  of  MyStructPtr  will  call  delete  for  us
```

Comment: Вы точно-точно все переписали из книги символ в символ?... Там не `MyStructPtr(MyStruct  *p)  :  _p(p)  {}`? Ну, а `_p(p)` - просто инициализация поля `_p` класса значением `p`.

Comment: я не переписал а скопировал :) Возможно в книге ошибка :)
<br>
получается запись:
 MyStructPtr(MyStruct *p) : _p(p) {}
<br>
равноценна: 
 MyStructPtr(MyStruct *p) { _p=p)};
правильно ?
Подскажите пожалуйста - как это правильно называется и где об этом можно прочитать ?( не нашел)

Comment: Правильно, это конструктор. Только там видимо опечатка и должно было быть `MyStructPtr(MyStruct  *p)  :  _p(p)` А после двоеточия написан список инициализации.